# Cambiar Valor de Miembro en C++

Tags: c++

Hola a todos estoy tratando de ***hookear*** la función `CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy` en una aplicación y quiero cambiar el valor de este miembro `pChainContext->TrustStatus.dwErrorStatus` ¿como puedo hacerlo? gracias!

```
BOOL WINAPI H_CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy(
LPCSTR                    pszPolicyOID,
PCCERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT      pChainContext,
PCERT_CHAIN_POLICY_PARA   pPolicyPara,
PCERT_CHAIN_POLICY_STATUS pPolicyStatus)
{
         pChainContext->TrustStatus.dwErrorStatus  = CERT_TRUST_IS_REVOKED; // MY Problem
         return TRUE; 
}
```

Comment: por favor adjuntar código ya que con la información que nos muestra nos será imposible ayudarte

Comment: Agregado, Gracias!

Comment: Que alguien me corriga, pero el prefijo **PC**??? no es `const pointer` ?

Comment: @Trauma No, **PC** no es `const pointer` en este contexto, pero sí lo es en `LPCSTR`: ***L**ong **P**ointer to **C**onst **S**tring*. Son alias de tipos propios de Microsoft y además de feos no existen en compiladores para otros Sistemas Operativos.

Comment: @MrJhon no entiendo qué quieres hacer. Debes alimentar la función `H_CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy` con un `pChainContext`, así que puedes modificarlo antes o después de llamar a la función.

Comment: @MrJhon, ¿ cual es el error exacto ?.

Comment: @Trauma `La expresión debe ser un valor L modificable` este en el editor y en el compilador`Error C3490 'dwErrorStatus' no se puede modificar porque se está obteniendo acceso a este elemento a través de un objeto const` , @PaperBirdMaster Ya la alimente con la función original.

Comment: Lo que yo decia. Un const *. PC... es un puntero constante.

Comment: @Trauma Hay forma de modificar el resultado de este puntero _usando Api monitor V2 se logra modificar_ ? así sea creando un nuevo contexto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cambiar** el valor de una variable `const` **no es posible**; sin embargo, **si** puedes forzar a que *deje de ser `const`*.

```
BOOL WINAPI H_CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy( ... ) {
  const_cast<PCERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT>(pChainContext)->TrustStatus.dwErrorStatus = CERT_TRUST_IS_REVOKED;
  return TRUE;
}
```

Ese código hará lo que pretendes.

Ahora bien, si lo que quieres es *engañar* a tu aplicación para alguna clase de prueba, la forma *más mejor* sería usar memoria dinámica y copiar allí los datos:

```
BOOL WINAPI H_CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy( ... ) {
  PCERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT *tmp = new CERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT;

  memcpy( tmp, pChainContext, sizeof( CERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT ) );

  tmp->TrustStatus.dwErrorStatus = CERT_TRUST_IS_REVOKED;

  return TRUE;
}
```

Y necesitarias alguna forma de que tu aplicación acceda a esa memoria que utilizas, en lugar de los datos originales.

Si lo que pretendes es *engañar* a la API criptográfica, modificando datos usados internamente por ella ... digamos que el comportamiento será **indefinido**. Lo mismo esa API se basó en esos datos para asignar o no asignar memoria, o lo hará en un futuro, y tus cambios haran que *se le valla la pinza*, que deje de funcionar, que funcione mal ...

**O** a lo mejor esa API te pasa *punteros* a **copias** de los datos reales que ella usa, en cuyo caso tus intentos serán baldíos.

**O** a lo mejor tienes suerte, no pasa nada, y funciona.

**O** ahora la engañas y en una futura actualización empieza a hacer *cosas raras*.

En general, **no es buena idea** modificar **a la fuerza** datos que no sabemos en realidad como son usados.

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Trauma Espero que a futuro __o no tan cercano, cambie esto__.